# Split data only in two array with multiple split operators

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a simple calculator where i am using split method to get two variables.How can i split the data with multiple operator but remember it should be splitted in two arrays only .

```
//split can be - + *
var operator= data.split('+'); //for now its only + but i want it for each opertor
var onfirst= operator[0];
var Onsecond = operator[1];
```

for now its only woking for + i dont want to code lengthy that i have to write split method for each operator so is there any possiblities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For regular expression use `var operator = data.split(/[-+*]/);`

Answer (score 0):

The javascript `split()` function accepts regular expressions.

```
var operator = data.split(/[-+*]/);
```

I'm not sure what you mean by split into two arrays only... if you're making a calculator, you'll need to do a lot more processing. Don't forget about [PEMDAS](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/orderops.htm).

Comment: can you little bit explain , i mean inside [ ] braces it is taking * + - right?

Comment: *Almost* anything inside the square brackets are matched separately... look at [this demo](http://regexr.com/3fjsf) - ignore the fact that the "g" flag is set because it doesn't matter when using the split function.

Comment: Can you also let me know : if a string contains 2343+2343+34 two + operator then how to count it that two operator is there?

Comment: It would be easier to use a library like [mathjs](https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs); or look at the source code and learn from it.